# How to pass a link URI from a XPS document to wpf app?

Tags: wpf, hyperlink, xps

is there a way to retrieve/catch a link URI in *xps* document that opened in a wpf application document viewer?
I'm using a document viewer control to open *xps* file:

```
  <Grid>
    <DocumentViewer x:Name="docview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <FixedDocument/>
    </DocumentViewer>
</Grid>
```

then there is a link in the Opened Document like the blue underlined text in picture:
[picture of viewer and opened document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvhZ.png)

I like the event of clicking the link begin handheld by my custom event handler.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. Can you provide more details please? Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Hyperlink">
            <Style.Setters>
                <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="OnClickHyperlinkElement" />
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DocumentViewer x:Name="docview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <FixedDocument/>
    </DocumentViewer>
</Grid>
```